# Rearrange dataframe to fit longitudinal model in R

Tags: r, dataframe, model, longitudinal

I have a dataframe where each entry relates to a job posting in the NHS specifying the week the job was posted, and what NHS Trust (and region) the job is in.

At the moment my dataframe looks something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
  NHS_Trust = sample(1:30,20,T),
  Week = sample(1:10,20,T),
  Region = sample(1:15,20,T))
```

And I would like to count the number of jobs for each week across each NHS Trust and assign that value to a new column 'jobs' so my dataframe looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df2 <- data.frame(
  NHS_Trust = rep(1:30, each=10),
  Week = rep(seq(1,10),30),
  Region = rep(as.integer(runif(30,1,15)),1,each = 10),
  Jobs = rpois(10*30, lambda = 2))
```

The dataframe may then be used to create a Poisson longitudinal multilevel model where I may model the number of jobs.

Comment: Please use a `set.seed` for reproducibiity.  Your 'df2' have more rows than 'df1'

Comment: I would like the new dataframe to have more rows in this instance as it records a value for every week of each NHS Trust

Comment: What is `Region`? It starts as a sampling of integers and ends up as "all 4s".

Comment: It would help if your "expected output" frame were based on the original data. This means you will need to manually calculate at least a portion of your expected results, hoping that somebody will find a programmatic method for you. (BTW: your edit changing `1:14` to `1:15` does nothing to compensate for the `size=1` you're using, causing a single number for the whole column.)

Comment: Sorry Region is supposed to be the region of the country that the NHS Trust is in, so the number should correspond with NHS_Trust, the code is wrong

Comment: Making an "expected output" frame on the original data is 74555 rows long, I feel this was is the best I can do for getting across what I want the output to be. I have fixed the code, but it should be noted the Region number and NHS Trust number should correspond to one another in the actual output as the NHS Trust lies inside that region.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `df1$Jobs <- 1; df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(Region, NHS_Trust, Week) %>% count(Jobs)`

Comment: Since I can't edit the comment anymore, this would be better: `df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(Region, NHS_Trust, Week) %>% count(); colnames(df2)[4] <- "Jobs"`

Comment: Thank you @Dunios, that is exactly what I'm looking for! Would it be possible to fill in the missing week values though where there was a week with no job posting? So the Jobs column would have a 0 in it for all the missing weeks (between 1-10 in the example).

Comment: @user553480 please refer to my answer. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` to count number of jobs across each `Region`, `NHS_Trust` and `Week` and use `complete` to fill in missing combinations.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  count(Region, NHS_Trust, Week, name = 'Jobs') %>%
  tidyr::complete(Region, Week = 1:10, fill = list(Jobs = 0))
```

Comment: I have reloaded R and now when I run this code I get an error: Error in count(., Region, NHS_Trust, Week, name = "Jobs") : 
  unused arguments (Week, name = "Jobs"). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, because I think you have `plyr` loaded along with `dplyr`. Restart R and load only `dplyr` or use `dplyr::count`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the data.table package you can group by, count and assign to a new column in a single expression. The syntax for data.tables is `dt[i, j, by]`. Here `i` is "with" - ie the subset of data specified by `i` or data in the order of `i` which is empty in this case so all data is used in its original order. The `j` tells what is to be done, here counting the the number of occurrences using `.N`, which is then assigned to the new variable `count` using the assign operator `:=`. The `by` takes a list of variables where the `j` operation is performed on each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1) 
df1[, count := .N, by = .(NHS_Trust, Week, Region)]
```

A tidyverse approach would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(NHS_Trust, Week, Region) %>% 
  count()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly along with @Dunois's solution! I especially appreciate the explanation.

However now I have missing entries for the weeks where there were 0 job postings, I was wondering if there was a way to fill in these missing values so that there is a complete list of 10 weeks for each NHS Trust, with a 0 listed for 'jobs' where no job exists for that week?

Comment: The data.table approach should retain all, tidyverse you may need to pop a join back to the original data - not sure off top of my head and without an example that reproduces the problem

Comment: But considering your data I dont see how zeros are possible...

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm moving my comment to an answer:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(Region, NHS_Trust, Week) %>% count(); colnames(df2)[4] <- "Jobs"

df2$combo <- paste0(df2$Region, "_", df2$NHS_Trust, "_", df2$Week)


for (i in 1:length(unique(df2$Region))){
  for (j in 1:length(unique(df2$NHS_Trust))){
    for (k in 1:length(unique(df2$Week))){

      curr_combo <- paste0(unique(df2$Region)[i], "_", 
                           unique(df2$NHS_Trust)[j], "_", 
                           unique(df2$Week)[k])

      if(!curr_combo %in% df2$combo){

        curdat <- data.frame(unique(df2$Region)[i], 
                             unique(df2$NHS_Trust)[j], 
                             unique(df2$Week)[k],
                             0,
                             curr_combo,
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        #cat(curdat)
        names(curdat) <- names(df2)
        df2 <- rbind(as.data.frame(df2), curdat)

      }
    }
  }
}

tail(df2)
#      Region NHS_Trust Week Jobs  combo
# 4495     15         1    4    0 15_1_4
# 4496     15         1    5    0 15_1_5
# 4497     15         1    8    0 15_1_8
# 4498     15         1    3    0 15_1_3
# 4499     15         1    6    0 15_1_6
# 4500     15         1    9    0 15_1_9
```

The `for loop` here check which `Region-NHS_Trust-Week` combinations are missing from `df2` and appends those to `df2` with a corresponding `Jobs` value of `0`. The checking is done with the help of the new variable `combo` which is just a concatenation of the values in the fields mentioned earlier separated by underscores.

Edit: I am plenty sure the people here can come up with something more elegant than this.